# Why can't I use js2coffee to convert `$`?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, js2coffee

I tried to convert the following code from javascript to coffeescript using [js2coffee website](http://js2coffee.org) as well as [js2coffee package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2coffee)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if (isPhoneDevice) {
      //mobile
    } else {
      //desktop
      // Initialize WOW.js
      wow = new WOW({
        offset: 50
      })
      wow.init();
    }
  });
```

but unfortunately both of them throws an error in the first line. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is complaining about the empty `if` clause. Write as

```
if (!isPhoneDevice) {
  wow...
}
```

or

```
if (isPhoneDevice) {
  null;
} else {
  wow...
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @curiousinternals for spotting my copy-paste error.

Comment: You forgot to invert the condition in your second example: It should be `if(isPhoneDevice)` instead of `if(!isPhoneDevice)`. Unfortunately I can't submit a one character edit.

Answer (score 0):

Js2coffee 2.0 is now out and fixes this. [Demo here](http://js2.coffee/#try:%0A%0A%20%20%24%28document%29.ready%28function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28isPhoneDevice%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fmobile%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdesktop%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Initialize%20WOW.js%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wow%20%3D%20new%20WOW%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20offset%3A%2050%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wow.init%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%29%3B).

btw: as the site would point out, you have a global variable leak you may want to fix (using `var wow = ...`).